# Solve this Recursive Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, recursion, integral-equations

How to solve this recursive integral? I do not even begin to understand how to solve this recursive integral. This doesn't even seem possible?

$$H{(x, y)} = \int_{t=0}^{t=2\pi} H(\frac{xt}{2},\frac{xt}{2})*2xt dt$$

This is intriguing me. What approaches exist for solving this?

EDIT:$$H{(x)} = \int_{t=0}^{t=2\pi} H\big(\frac{xt}{2}\big)*2xt \, dt$$

Comment: But its been integrated wrt what t or x

Comment: i think you want to say $H(x)=\int_{0}^{2\pi}2xtH(\frac{xt}{2})dt$.

Comment: Integrated with respect to t. @Basti, I see what you are thinking, but H is a function of two variables, integrated with respect to t. I cannot arbitrarily simplify it to H(x).

Comment: @Basti However, I would be interested in solving that too, that is also a recursive integral that I cannot understand how to solve.

Comment: $\int_{0}^{2\pi}2xtH(\frac{xt}{2})dt$ is a function only of $x$. that is what confuses me.

Comment: @kobeSystem IMO doesn't seem to be possible due to the way $H(x,t)$ is defined

Comment: What have you tried? Obvious attacks are differentiation of both sides and integration by parts. The former loses a bit of information since the limits dissappear, and the latter isn't a surefire method. Also, your function on the RHS is only a function of $x$, since the $t$ dissappear during integration

Comment: Some people have already tried to point out although not that obvious: The right hand side does only give an expression of $x$ since the $t$ is just a dummy variable of integration, but the left hand side contains $t$. Something thus seems to be not correct with your formula.

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer for the second integral

Consider the function $G(x) = xH(x/8)$. Rescaling $x$ in the integral and making the appropriate $u$-substitution gives
$$
G(x) = \int_0^{\pi x} G(u) du
$$
Differentiating both sides gives
$$
G'(x) = G(\pi x)
$$
a rather curious differential equation I'm not sure of the solution to.