# Solution to the differential equation $G'(x) = G(\pi x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2244379/solve-this-recursive-integral/2306593#2306593), I came across the differential equation
$$
G'(x) = G(\pi x)
$$
Despite its apparent simplicity, I couldn't think of an elementary solution to it. Does this have a known solution?

Comment: Other than $G(x)=0$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Ideally yes.

Comment: If you assume that $G$ has a Maclaurin's series expansion you get a series that converges only at $x=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Let me try a power series

$$
G(x) =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n x^n
$$

$$
G(\pi x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\pi^n x^n
$$

$$
G'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)a_{n+1}x^n
$$

Setting $G'(x) = G(\pi x)$ we have the following recursion relation among the coefficients of the power series $G(x)$.

$$
a_{n+1}=\frac{\pi^n}{n+1}a_{n},\;\;\;n=0,1,\cdots
$$

$$
a_1=a_0
$$

$$
a_2=\frac{\pi}{2}a_1=\frac{\pi}{2!}a_0
$$

$$
a_3=\frac{\pi^2}{3}a_2=\frac{\pi^3}{3!}a_0
$$

$$
a_4=\frac{\pi^3}{4}a_3=\frac{\pi^6}{4!}a_0
$$

$$
a_n=\frac{\pi^{\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}j}}{n!}a_0
$$

$$
\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}j=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}
$$

$$
a_n=\frac{\pi^{n(n-1)/2}}{n!}
$$

$$
G(x)=a_0\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\pi^{n(n-1)/2}}{n!}x^n
$$

$$
G(x)=a_0 G_0(x)
$$

where $G_0(x)$ is the solution of the above equation for which $G_0(0)=1$.

$$
G_0(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\pi^{n(n-1)/2}}{n!}x^n
$$

I'm concerned about the convergence properties of the power series but this is my best attempt at the problem.

Comment: I think that @JohnWaylandBales posted a comment on regards to the convergence

Comment: This is the first thing that I tried, but the series diverges except at $x=0$. Use the Ratio test. This would work, however, for $G^\prime(x)=G(x/\pi)$.